# Move Variables from a jList into a different Button

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, call, jlist

I am working on a program that has multiple jLists. The user can select different items to create a skate board and the program will calculate the subtotal, sales tax, and final total. I am using the Netbeans JFrame form so I don't think I can put things into arrays for this program. My problem is that I'm stuck on how to call variables from the jLists to a different action button so that it can calculate the subtotal, sales tax, and total.

Here's an example of one of my jLists:

```
private void jList1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        // Get values from List 1 for Decks
        String v = jList1.getSelectedValue();
        int i = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
        
        if(i == 0){
            thrasher = 60;
            
        }
        if(i == 1){
            dictator = 45;
            
        }
        if(i ==2){
            streetKing = 50;
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

and here's the code I'm trying to move these variables to:

```
private void calulateBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        double total =0;
        double sbtotal = 0;
        double tax = 0;
        double SALESTAX = 0.07;
        
        Integer l1 = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
        Integer l2 = jList2.getSelectedIndex();
        Integer l3 = jList3.getSelectedIndex();
        Integer l4 = jList4.getSelectedIndex();
        
        
        subTotal.setText(Double.toString(sbtotal));
        
        sbtotal = Double.parseDouble(subTotal.getText());
        tax = sbtotal * SALESTAX;
        total = tax + sbtotal;
        
        salesTax.setText(Double.toString(tax));
        finalTotal.setText(Double.toString(total));
        
    }
```

I'm pretty sure the calulateBtn function is totally wrong. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"Netbeans JFrame form so I don't think I can put things into arrays for this program"* the form editor has little to do with that, you can create your own array with manually, besides, I'd discourage the use of the form editor generally

Comment: A [mcve] would go along way to helping use understand the issue, but, from the sounds of it, you're misunderstanding the difference between "instance" and "local" variables

Comment: Honestly, it just sounds like you're trying to run before you can walk here. Build a version of your program that just takes user input via Scanner until you know what you're doing and then really go through a Java Swing tutorial until you actually have a sense of what each component does and how they all work together before you try anything fancy. A great way to stall your learning is to try to do too much, too early.

Comment: So I made this way more complicated than it needed to be! I moved the if statements to the calculateBtn method and everything worked!